# Add Task Scheduler

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I´m developing an Apache Cordova application and I want to know if I can add tasks to the scheduler device.

I have to run an alarm and notification at a specific time, how can I do this?

I thought about adding a task to the scheduler device and delegate responsibility.

This is possible? At least Android 4.4

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first off all: Yes, you're of course able to do so. Sebastian Katzer wrote a plugin for that. It can be found here: [Cordova - Local Notification Plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/).

This Plugin allows you to trigger scheduled Events or for example: Trigger events every Monday at 6 a.m. The Code for a standard notification looks like this:

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    id: 1,
    title: "Production Jour fixe",
    text: "Duration 1h",
    firstAt: monday_9_am,
    every: "week",
    sound: "file://sounds/reminder.mp3",
    icon: "http://icons.com/?cal_id=1",
    data: { meetingId:"123#fg8" }
});

cordova.plugins.notification.local.on("click", function (notification) {
    joinMeeting(notification.data.meetingId);
});
```

The message looks like a Notification - a picture of that can be found here: [Picture - Katzer Local Notifications](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/blob/example/images/android.png)

There also is a wiki which can be found here: [Local Notifications by Katzer Wiki](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/11.-Samples)

Hope i helped you! Let me know if you need further information!

Comment: Thanks, It´s just the library I looking for.