# Phonegap Delete localstorage Everyday

Tags: javascript, cordova, local-storage

I have a counter and I save it in localstorage. I want to delete this localStorage Key everyday.
So is there a way to programmatically clear localstorage every night at 11 o'clock;

Thank You!

Comment: Instead of localstorage use sessionStorage, the data  gets cleared when the page session ends. I do not know if what you ask is possible.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. I want the variable to be saved in localstorage for a day. So if the person open the app the next day the counter will be started from 0.

Comment: @Konst in cordova? localstorage is the way to go.
OP, its not possible when the application is not opened. But you can check when the app is initializing if its past 11, and clear the storage

Comment: That's a good way to to that. I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: @RFLdev Is there any plugin to check that? Thank You!

Comment: You're using the key stored in LocalStorage for some proccess or something like that, you could check before use if it is expired.

Answer (score 0):

This [notification plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/) should do the trick for you.This Plugin allows you to trigger scheduled Events. Also you can have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747646/add-task-scheduler) for more info.